# With redux form, how to combine values for initialValues?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm currently building a component to allow a user to edit their profile settings. The form has fields like:

```
first_name
last_name
```

The redux form is currently setting initialValues correctly like so:

```
Profile = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.profiles.find(el => el.id === state.currentUser.user_id)
  })
)(Profile)
```

The problem is I need to also include UserSettings in this form, so I'm trying to do this:

```
    Profile = connect(
      state => ({
        initialValues: state.profiles.find(el => el.id === state.currentUser.user_id),
        initialValues: {
          notification_email_product_feature_updates: state.user_settings.notification_email_product_feature_updates
}
      })
    )(Profile)
```

but the above does not work... How can I add additional initialValues which are in a different state object?

I also tried the following but this is not setting the value:

```
Profile = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: {
      first_name: state.profiles.find(el => el.id === state.currentUser.user_id) ? state.profiles.find(el => el.id === state.currentUser.user_id).first_name : '',
    }
  })
)(Profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, but you have to make sure that you got something in this `state.user_settings.notification_email_product_feature_updates`:

```
    Profile = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: 
        {
            currentUser: state.profiles.find(el => el.id === state.currentUser.user_id),
            settings: state.user_settings.notification_email_product_feature_updates
        }
    })
    )(Profile)
```